# Chord plot ggplot2 overlapping chords

Tags: r, ggplot2, chord-diagram

I am working on a dataset where we have trying to generate a chord plot and we are trying to have the chords overlap within each variable. So for instance, each variable has a set number in it (102) and I am wondering if there is a way to have each variable have the same number in it and then have connections coming out of it (such as 38, 21, 45, 30) in which the chords would overlap because the amount of connections is greater than the number in the variable? Such as what is shown in the image.

[image: Chord image showing overlaping chords]

Please let me know if there is a way to have the chords overlap?

Thank you!

Comment: OP, can you clarify what you are looking to do in the question and provide a representative example using a built-in dataset or another representative example?  Chord Diagrams naturally overlap, so I'm not sure the nature of your question.  Are you referencing that for some entries on the diagram the sum of the connections is > 100?  Connections on the diagram are by convention broken down into proportions, not absolute values.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was hoping to have a set value for each of the variables around the circle and then have chords whose sum would be greater than the value of the variable come out of the chords so that they overlap in the variable rather than summing all the chords for the variable together. So if the variable 1 was 100, but the chords coming out of variable 1 going to variable 2, variable 3 and variable 4 were 78, 89, and 43 rather than having Variable 1 become 210 keeping variable 1 at 100 and having the chords come out. Sorry if it isn't super clear. Thank you!

Comment: You probably will want to check out the `circlize` package.  [See some examples of what you can do with that here](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/).